# Samsung Galaxy S in boot loop after following cyanogen mod's full update guide

Tags: rooting, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, boot-loop

I have been following this guide to root my [Samsung Galaxy S](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide) smartphone. I've followed it to the letter, but after I load the new kernel to the phone, the phone gets stuck in a boot loop. The phone restarts after the kernel is loaded, it gets to the "Galaxy S" splashscreen, and then it goes off and restarts. Nothing else happens.

I have tried to get in to the recovery mode by holding the power, home and volume up button, and all this seems to do is hang the phone when it displays the same splashscreen. It does nothing else.

I'm really stuck, I've tried reloading the kernel several times since but nothing happens (I can get in to Download mode). I've also read on another forum that you can press the power button and the volume up and down buttons, but these don't do anything.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry to see you in this state. The link that you are referring is about flashing CyanogenMod and not just rooting. Of course, by flashing CM successfully you would have rooted, but just asking you possibly mistook something? If you had followed the procedure in that page, you would have installed ClockworkMod Recovery and backed up your previous ROM. In that case you can go to recovery and restore your previous ROM.

Comment: I ended up reloading a firmware update to the phone, but that's fixed the boot loop problem but has now meant I've locked my phone to the T-Mobile network by accident.

Comment: @mickburkejnr Did you use the kernel from my answer?

Comment: I did, but not in the comment your referring to. I used the kernel from your answer at the finish and it all works fine.

Comment: That should be the same kernel. I just copied the information.

Comment: Well I tried to root my phone today and it didn't work. So I went back and followed the same guide but downloaded the kernel you provided. I am now the proud owner of a rooted Samsung Galaxy S running ICS 4.0.3. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Edit

Honestly, I am not 100% sure that this was really a problem related to the kernel. I think that the "problem" could be also caused by the fact that pressing the home key in recovery mode results in a reboot. The correct way to select a recovery item is to press the power button.

## Original post

I had the same issue two days ago. The problem was the kernel. After switching to [the kernel that was mentioned a few wiki changes](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide&diff=prev&oldid=14501) before it worked like a charm.

**Kernel:** http://cmw.22aaf3.com/aries/gt-i9000/root/Hardcore-speedmod-i9000.zip

**MD5:** afccda1f4efb560398dd5bc107bb7a69

I even [(re-)added this information](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide&diff=16287&oldid=15155) but it was [again reverted.](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide&diff=16288&oldid=16287) :-(

Comment: Weird, you think if you and others had the issue they would leave it accepted on the wiki.

Comment: I have the same issues with my phone but the Kernel you uploaded is not available anymore. Can you please re upload it once again please?

Comment: I am not sure if I still have the kernel file. Until then: Check my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the kernel. I had also faced this problem before and got out of the boot loop. Follow the instructions given below.

1. Download the stock firmware from www.sammobile.com
2. Download Heimdall Suite.
3. Extract the firmware package and copy the zImage file into the Heimdall Suite directory.
4. Install the driver for the phone.
5. Boot the phone into download mode by pressing <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Home button</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>.
6. Connect the phone to the computer using the USB cable supplied along with the phone.
7. Open Command Prompt and change the directory to Heimdall Suite.
8. Now type `heimdall flash --kernel zImage`
9. A blue bar will come on the screen. After the flash is complete, the phone will reboot normally.
10. After the reboot, go to the Apps screen to check if the Superuser app is installed. If Superuser is installed, your phone is rooted.

To install Cyanogenmod, follow the following instructions:

1. Copy the rom to a folder in the sd card.
2. Copy the zImage file provided by Cyanogenmod into the Heimdall Suite directory.
3. Boot the phone into download mode.
4. Connect the phone to the computer.
5. Open Command Prompt.
6. Change the directory to Heimdall Suite and flash the kernel using the following command: `heimdall flash --kernel zImage`
7. The phone will reboot and go into a bootloop.
8. Turn off the phone by removing the battery.
9. Boot the phone into Recovery mode by holding <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Home button</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>.
10. Now flash the rom using the method mentioned [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide)
11. You will now have Cyanogenmod installed on your phone.