# phone stuck while loading cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, hardware, boot-loop

I am using a *Samsung Galaxy Y.* Everytime I switch on my phone it goes from samsung logo to cyanogenmod loading.

What do i do? I have waited for an hour.

Comment: What did you do before this happened? Did you flash something? Installed something?

Comment: I have just added the `boot-loop` tag to your question. For first-aid, please check its [tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info), then report back with whether it solved your issue (and how), or where you're stuck and what you've tried.

Comment: Did CyanogenMod ever work on your phone before, or did it start as soon as you installed it?

Comment: i tried everything in recovery mod but it still brings me to cyanogenmod loadinh

Comment: Sounds like a boot loop: see [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27968/samsung-galaxy-s-in-boot-loop-after-following-cyanogen-mods-full-update-guide?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

It might take a minute or five, but certainly not an hour. But I know what happened to you as it happened to me too when I flashed my first rom.

Keeping it short: the ever-looping boot animation you're seeing is silently saying that you forgot to clean the caches after you've flashed your CyanogenMod rom.

To fix that, do:

1. Reboot into ClockworkMod.
2. Whipe the *"Dalvik cache"*.
3. Optionally, while the *"Cache"*.
4. Reboot into Cyanogenmod.

Most of the time, it's simple an unwhiped *"Dalvik cache"* messing things up. Yet, in the unlikely case that shouldn't fix it (for example - when you weren't running a previous CyanogenMod rom before you flashed your current one), you'll have to do a *"Factory Reset"* too. But 1-4 should get you going, so I would not factory-reset it on the first attempt. ;)